# Using site's icon in the footer like Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, design, footer

In Stack Overflow (main and meta), the footer has the icon of Stack Overflow which leads to the **Home pages** of [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) (and [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) ).

[image]

Other sites have their name in bold in the footer (Stack Overflow too does) which leads to their Home page, but can they also be made to have their respective logos in their footer which leads to their Home page like Stack Overflow?

For example

[image]